# help understanding interaction between UIVIewController and UIView subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

here's the current situation:

TestViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {
}
@end
```

TestViewController.m:

```
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "draw.h"
@implementation TestViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
draw.rectColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.6 brightness:0.6 alpha:1].CGColor;
[draw setNeedsDisplay];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
 }
@end
```

draw.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface draw : UIView {
UIColor* rectColor;
}

@property (retain) UIColor* rectColor;

@end
```

draw.m:

```
#import "draw.h"

@implementation draw

@synthesize rectColor;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rectangle {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorRef myColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:1 brightness:0.61 alpha:1].CGColor;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, myColor);
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 95.0, 110.0));
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

then in the Interface Builder I've created a 90x115 UIView and set it's Class Identity to "draw".
When I run the application (without the two non-compiling lines) it displays a nice red rectangle in the middle of the screen. My goal is it be able to change the color of the rectangle from within my TestViewController. However when I compile the test app I get the following compiler errors:

```
error: accessing unknown 'setRectColor:' class method
error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found
warning: 'draw' may not respond to '+setNeedsDisplay'
```

I know I am missing "a link" between my TestViewController and draw, but can't figure out how to go about implementing it. I have tried various tricks, but nothing worked. 
Could someone please explain what needs to be done in order for

```
draw.rectColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.6 brightness:0.6 alpha:1].CGColor;
[draw setNeedsDisplay];
```

to compile and work ?
(I would use this knowledge to create a different method in TestViewController, I am just testing it inside viewDidLoad)

Comment: hey, I took out the app delegate stuff, as it was making the question very long and definitely wasn't connected to this error. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. I wasn't sure, that's why I put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, you set the rectColor property and call setNeedsDisplay: on draw, but draw is your class. You need to do it to the instance. You shouldn't need to create a new property for this because UIViewController defines the view property. Just use `self.view` instead of `draw` in your viewDidLoad method. Also, remove the `.CGColor` at the end of the line.

Second, your drawRect: method ignores that color and uses its own. Change

```
CGColorRef myColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:1 brightness:0.61 alpha:1].CGColor;
```

to

```
CGColorRef myColor = self.rectColor.CGColor;
```

Comment: you're an ace, sir. as soon as I switched the CGColorRef line, things started to click. I knew there was something I was missing. Now I know. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The big problem here is that you haven't declared a property for `draw`; you have to do this and link it up to your Interface Builder object if you want to access it. The solution is to create a property that will hold the `draw` object, and synthesize its setters and getters using `@synthesize`. (that last piece is why you're getting the error.)

Once you change the code to what I have below, you'll need to make the proper connection in Interface Builder, or else you'll find that your code changes simply have no effect, even though they're error free.

Capitalize your class names (always!), and then try this:

TestViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Draw; //forward class declaration

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet Draw *drawCopy;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Draw *drawCopy;
@end
```

Then, for TestViewController.m:

```
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "Draw.h"
@implementation TestViewController

@synthesize drawCopy;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    self.drawCopy.rectColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.6 brightness:0.6 alpha:1];
    [self.drawCopy setNeedsDisplay];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [drawCopy release];
    [super dealloc];
 }

@end
```

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: I think I've done the changes right, but I still get an error ........ warning: passing argument 1 of 'setRectColor:' from incompatible pointer type  ....... this is at  self.drawCopy.rectColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:1 brightness:0.9 alpha:1].CGColor;

Comment: ah, whoops -- try removing the `.CGColor` from the end, so you're just assigning a `UIColor` to the property. I'll change my code to reflect that!

Comment: cool. now it compiles. I've hooked up File's Owner to drawCopy outlet in IB , but when I run the app I don't see a change in color. Could it have something to the with the fact that in the UIView subclass I do ..... CGColorRef myColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:1 brightness:0.5 alpha:1].CGColor; CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, myColor); .... but in the ViewController I do: self.drawCopy.rectColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:1 brightness:0.5 alpha:0.5];

Comment: why not forget about overriding drawRect:, and just use [self setBackgroundColor:(the UIColor you need)]; ? Or, better yet, just set the background color in interface builder.

Comment: all working fine now. this was the key change: CGColorRef myColor = self.rectColor.CGColor;

Answer (score 0):

you definde `UIColor* rectColor;` but u write an CGColor too it

```
draw.rectColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.6 brightness:0.6 alpha:1].CGColor;
```

try

```
self.drawCopy.rectColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.6 brightness:0.6 alpha:1];
```